# skip second row of dataframe while reading csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to skip the second row of a data file while reading a csv file in python.

I am using the following code :

```
imdb_data = pd.read_csv('IMDB_data.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1",skiprows = 2)
```

Comment: We need more details. Please read the help center on proper question writing.

Comment: I am new to python programming , my question is that I have a file IMDB_data , where I want to skip the second row while loading it as a csv file in python.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code will ommit the first two lines of your csv.
If you want the second line to be ommitted (but the first one included) just do this minor change:

```
imdb_data = pd.read_csv('IMDB_data.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1",skiprows = [1])
```

Comment: file_contents = pd.read_csv('IMDB_data.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1",skiprows = [2]) works not [1]

Comment: @ShamsuddinAltamash Matina and timgeb are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) we can learn that if you supply an integer `n` for `skiprows`, the first `n` rows are skipped. If you want to skip single lines explicitly by line number (0 indexed), you must supply a list-like argument.

In your specific case, that would be `skiprows=[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The question has already answered. If one wants to skip number of rows at once, one can do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv("transaction_activity.csv", skiprows=list(np.arange(1, 13)))
```

It will skip rows from second up to 12 by keeping your original columns in the dataframe, as it is counted '0'.

Hope it helps for similar problem.